# How to implement async await in Cypress test?

Tags: javascript, async-await, cypress

I have a spec file with some duplicated tests and I need to create a loop to avoid this duplication. But JS asynchrony nature makes it impossible. I guess I need to use async await or promises instead of existing solution. How can I implement it?

Here is a code snippet from existing spec which produces 9 tests (actually test suites 5 it() each). And the problem is that each of these 9 tests uses the same data defined in the last branch of the switch (case 9). Which means that all branches of switch are executed and only then the tests start having the last branch set of values. Finally all of those 9 tests (test suites) are the same test (test suite) executed 9 times.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  switch(i) {
    case 0:
      name = 'name 0'
      url = 'url 0'
      product = 'product 0'
      isMultipleProductsDropdown = true / false
      stateDropdownSelector = '#selector 0'
      store = 'store name 0'
      storeDisplayed = 'store displayed 0'
      billingAddressLabel = 'billingAddressLabel 0'
      status = 'status 0'
      break
    ..............
  case 9:
    name = 'name 9'
    url = 'url 9'
    product = 'product 9'
    isMultipleProductsDropdown = true / false
    stateDropdownSelector = '#selector 9'
    store = 'store name 9'
    storeDisplayed = 'store displayed 9'
    billingAddressLabel = 'billingAddressLabel 9'
    status = 'status 9'
    break
  }

  context('context 1', () => {
    it('Test 1-1', () => {
      ..................
    })
    
    it('Test 1-2', () => {
      ..................
    })
  })

  context('context 2', () => {
    it('Test 2-1', () => {
      ..................
    })
    
    it('Test 2-2', () => {
      ..................
    })

    it('Test 2-3', () => {
      ..................
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: You are well off the mark with `async /await`, it's not supported by Cypress. Please review this question [Cypress fixtures best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72387981/16997707) and this [Cypress/Testing Dynamic Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70063249/16997707) and this [How to repeat actions in cypress and get the result of each action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60269807/16997707)

Comment: That seems like a hassle to maintain. Surely there is a better way to handle all the inputs for your tests in this particular spec file.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see why you're getting this problem, logically the code looks ok.

But can I suggest moving the data outside the loop (i.e remove the switch). This way is more conventional as given in the Cypress documentation.

```js
const datas = [
  {
      name : 'name 0'
      url : 'url 0'
      product : 'product 0'
      isMultipleProductsDropdown : true,
      stateDropdownSelector : '#selector 0'
      store : 'store name 0'
      storeDisplayed : 'store displayed 0'
      billingAddressLabel : 'billingAddressLabel 0'
      status : 'status 0'
  },
  {
      name = 'name 9'
      ...
  }
]

datas.forEach((data,i) => {

  context(`context ${i}`, () => {
    it(`Test ${i}-1', () => {

      // extract the data values  
      const {name, url, product, isMultipleProductsDropdown, etc } = data

      ..................
    })
    
    it(`Test ${i}-2`, () => {

      // extract the data values  
      const {name, url, product, isMultipleProductsDropdown, etc } = data

      ..................
    })
  })
})
```

The "context(`context ${i}`, () => {" etc uses backticks and `${}` to insert the index number into the string.

The data can be in a separate fixture file, which is read into the test, if preferred.

Comment: Thank you very much @user16695029! It was really helpful and works fine. The only problem which was found (actually I noticed it before) is that Cypress works really bad with big tests (this one has about 50 it() ) and crashes during tests execution. I tried to reduce numTestsKeptInMemory in config file to 20 tests (50 is default value) but it didn't really help. Thank you very much for your solution once more.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle really big data sets and are concerned about memory usage, consider using the [Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api).

The aim is to run the tests individually from a nodeJs process and give the runner a chance to clean up memory between tests.

Roughly, these are the steps:

- create a `scripts` folder at the project root
- add a file `run-tests.js` in this folder

  ```js
  const cypress = require('cypress')

  const data = [
    {
      name : 'name 0'
      url : 'url 0'
      product : 'product 0'
      isMultipleProductsDropdown : true,
      stateDropdownSelector : '#selector 0'
      store : 'store name 0'
      storeDisplayed : 'store displayed 0'
      billingAddressLabel : 'billingAddressLabel 0'
      status : 'status 0'
    },
    {
      name = 'name 9'
      ...
    }
  ]

  data.forEach(d => {

    cypress.run({
      spec: './cypress/e2e/my-spec.cy.js',
      env: {
        data: d
      })
    })
  })
  ```
- create your spec so that it reads each `data` from `Cypress.env('data')`

  **my-spec.cy.js**

  ```js
  const data = Cypress.env('data')
  const { name, url, product, isMultipleProductsDropdown, etc } = data

  context(`context: ${name}`, () => {

    it(`Test ${name}-1', () => {
      ..................
    })

    it(`Test ${name}-2`, () => {
      ..................
    })
  })
  ```
- call the script from command line

  ```js
  node ./scripts/run-tests.js
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe check out asynchronous generators or iterators, example copied from MDN

Or as above.

P.S. The while loop has the best performance, so maybe try doing a test on that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncGenerator

**example:**--sync generator

```js
function* gen() {
  while (true) {
    const value = yield;
    console.log(value, '-----generator');
  }
}

const g = gen();
var i =0
var arr = [{data:'1'},{data:'2'},{data:'3'},{data:'4'},{data:'5'}]
g.next(0) //first value not return

while(i<=arr.length-1) {
g.next(arr[i]); 
console.log(arr[i], '-----loop');

i++
}
```

**example2:** -- not generator (you can without async/await)

```js
async function create() {
var i=0
var arr = [{data:'1'},{data:'2'},{data:'3'},{data:'4'},{data:'5'}]

while(i<arr.length) {
console.log('create', arr[i])
await read(arr[i])
i++
}}

async function read(val) {
console.log('read',val)
}

create()
```

Or use RxJS libary from(arr)...

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from

There are different ways you have to search and choose the best one